# Work on two charges in mutually retarded field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Consider two particles with charges $q$ and $Q$ and with an initial distance of $3L$. Now I move each charge a distance $L$ closer to the other, such that the final distance is $L$. The initial and final velocity of the particles is zero. I'm trying to calculate the total work I have to do in two cases: When the movement happens with speeds much lower than the speed of light, and when the movement happens with speeds close to the speed of light and the particles are accelerated very quickly.

In the fast case, if I accelerate the particles (almost) instantly to $v\approx c$, then each charge only sees the retarded field of the other charge. When I stop the particles at their final positions, the change in the electromagnetic field didn't have enough time to travel the remaining distance $L$ to the other charge. This means each charge only sees the "rest field" of the other charge during the whole movement.

The total work done in the fast case is $$W_f=2\int_0^L \frac{qQ}{(3L-x)^2}dx=\frac{qQ}{3L}$$ Since the situation is symmetric, the total work is two times the work done on one charge. In the integral, the distance decreases from $3L$ to $2L$, because the charge doesn't know yet that the other charge is moving too. In other words, the retarded field the charge has to move through is equal to that of a charge at rest at $x=3L$.

In the slow case, the total work done is $$W_s=2\int_0^L \frac{qQ}{(3L-2x)^2}=\frac{2qQ}{3L}$$
Here, the distance decreases by $2x$ if the charge moves a distance $x$, because the other charge is coming towards it.

After the movement, there are still the deformed fields propagating through space, however I hold both particles at a fixed position (via external force). Since they don't move during that time, there is no work done by the fields or me on the charges, so we can wait until the field normalizes.

In both cases the charges are in the same state after the movement, so the potential energy between them is the same. How to explain the difference in work done in the two cases?

My first tought was, that this must be due to the electromagnetic radiation that is emitted in the fast case by accelerating the particles. Since the radiation is carrying energy away, extra work must be done on the charges to accelerate them. The extra force against which this extra work must be done would be the Abraham-Lorentz force, which each charge experiences from its own field. This implies that the work done in the fast case must be larger than in the slow case.

But the above calculation shows that the work done in the fast case is lower. Also, the Abraham-Lorentz force and therefore the work that is converted into radiation only depends on the acceleration of the particle and is ignorant to the presence of the other charge. The energy gap between the two cases however depends on the charge and distance of both particles, something which isn't included in the Abraham-Lorentz force. Therefore it can't explain this energy gap. Moving charges slowly apart and moving them fast together would create energy.

How to explain the difference in work done in the two cases?

Comment: If you include the Abraham-Lorentz force, then your calculation for the total work done to bring the particles from $3L$ to $L$ is wrong, since you are missing the work required to work against the self-force. Your integral only computes the work against the force of the particle on the other particle. Note that self-force applies when the particles are treated as finite size bodies, and the force is due to the retarded fields coming from parts of the particle acting on other parts of the same particle.

Comment: What I think is interesting is that there is another formalization where the particles are point-like, and the Lorentz force law uses only the fields from the other particles to compute the force on one particle (this is the direct particle interaction model). In this model there is no Abraham-Lorentz force since the particle always moves slower than its own retarded field. So I am not sure how to explain the work difference in that setting.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes I know that, but my argument is, that the energy of radiation emitted depends on the acceleration profile. The work gap I calculated depends on the distance L and charges q and Q. I can choose a different acceleration profile but keep the other constants the same. 
Lets say I move them slowly apart and get the energy $W_s$ and then I move them together quickly and do the work $W_f$.

Comment: The net work over one cycle is then $W=W_s-W_f=E_r(a)$ and has to be equal to the emitted radiation $E_r$, but the Radiation depends (from Lorentz-Abraham) only on the acceleration $a$, while $W$ doesn't depend on $a$, it depends on $L$ and $Q$. It isn't possible that W=E_r for all parameters that I can freely choose. So I know my calculation is "wrong", because it doesn't include the Abraham-Lorentz-Force, but that Force has the wrong dependencies and can't possibily explain the energy gap.

Comment: I see. I'll have to think more carefully about the way the self force acts here. So your argument is that the work done against the self forces must somehow equal $-W = -W_s + W_f = \frac{qQ}{3L}$, but that the Abraham-Lorentz force has a dependence on $a$, which is absent in this work gap.

Comment: @TobErnack Exactly! Also, W has a dependence on both charges q and Q, where the Abraham-Lorentz force only depends on the accelerated charge q. 
Trying to make it more rigorous: Energy of emitted radiation from Larmor formula (which can be derived from Abraham-Lorentz) would be $$E_r=\int_{t(0)}^{t(L)} q^2a^2 dt $$ (I dropped all constants). But Larmor is only true for small velocities, but for fast velocities there are more complicated formulas, but the dependencies are always the same.

Comment: I think the dependence on both $q$ and $Q$ is not surprising because there is self-force on both charges (you accelerate both pretty fast when bringing them together). So the work on both charges needs to be included and this is not symmetric. By the way, for relativistic speeds you need to use the Abraham-Lorentz-Dirac force instead of the Abraham-Lorentz force. I don't think this elucidates where the dependence on $a$ goes, but just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @TobErnack Yes, you're right about that.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very familiar with the details of the self-force. Maybe it is possible that when you compute the total work done by the self-forces (without approximations) the dependence on $a$ somehow cancels out somewhere. But this looks hard to believe, so I don't know. And as I mentioned, the same problem arises if you consider point-like particles and direct particle interaction without self-forces. It is also puzzling to me.

Comment: Earlier I pointed out that at some time the ripples from the retarded fields emitted during acceleration/deceleration would reach the other particle. You are correct that since you are maintaining the particles fixed, no net work is done on the particles. But work will likely be spent elsewhere to modify the external forces so that particles are fixed. I am not sure how you'd change the external force without moving something somewhere. Maybe this needs to be taken into account.

Comment: I have been reading a lot about self forces, but I'm not sure what you mean by the "direct particle interaction model", under what keywords can i find more about that?

And about the technical realization: I only consider these extreme conditions because its conceptually easier and makes the problem more obvious. But it still works with velocities slower than c and more realistic accelerations. We can also choose other distances. So maybe some sort of mechanical grabber with charged metal spheres in its hand? It could hold the spheres by friction without moving...

Comment: @TobErnack - This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Comments are only for clarifying questions when they are unclear. If you know the nswer, you are welcome to post it.

Comment: @Azzinoth I created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97796/discussion-on-question-by-azzinoth-work-on-two-charges-in-mutually-retarded-fie) we can continue discussion there if you want.